Getting issue in parallel execution of rxjava async calls in java implementaion
I am new to reactive prorgramming in java using rxjava.
I have an implementation in java in which I am making an async call to an external service. Based on the response of this i am calling another service which is again an async call. Both calls are in rxjava single.
This whole process needs to be run in parallel for batches.
So say I have 100 items to be processed then I am creating 4 batches of 25 as size of each batch. I am running 25 items parallely but the batches are sequential.
The issue I am facing is I am getting a NPE in this implementation.
Below is the my implementation
private Map<String, List<List<String>>> firstAPICall(
            List<STRequest> stList,
            int batchSize,
            int numberOfBatches,
            final String mainTraceId
    ) {
        log.debug("Main Trace ID: {} Initiating firstAPICall", mainTraceId);

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        //TODO : update the thread count as per the tps supported by downstream service
        final List<Integer> batchList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfBatches; i++) {
            batchList.add(i);
        }
        Map<String, List<List<String>>> stMap = new HashMap<>();
        int parallelThreadsCount = batchList.size();
        Disposable disposable = Flowable.fromIterable(batchList)
                .parallel(parallelThreadsCount)
                .runOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(batchIndex -> fetchStoreSubList(storeList, batchSize, batchIndex))
                .flatMapIterable(stList -> stList)
                .flatMap(stRequest -> {
                    String traceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    return stDao.getStDetails(
                                    stRequest.getStUUID(), stRequest.isDetailsFlag(), stRequest.getCode())
                            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                                log.error("Trace: {} Error occured {}", traceId, throwable.getMessage());
                                return new StResponse();
                            })
                            .map(stResponse -> {
                                stResponse.getSt().getSts().removeIf(i -> i.getNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(stRequest.getStNumber()));
                                return stResponse;
                            })
                            .flatMap(stResponse -> Single.just(fetchData(stResponse, traceId))) // line 1 - call to second api
                            .toFlowable();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .subscribe(responseList -> {
                    responseList.forEach(stMap::putAll);
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                });
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Trace: {} Error while waiting for count down", mainTraceId);
        }
        disposable.dispose();
        return stMap;
    }

// second api implementation
private Map<String, List<List<String>>> fetchData (StResponse stResponse,
                                                       final String traceId) 
{
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        log.debug("CRdata Trace id: {} Initiating fetchCRData for", traceId);

        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(stResponse) ||
                ObjectUtils.isEmpty(stResponse.getStore()) ||
                ObjectUtils.isEmpty(stResponse.getStore().getStores())) {
            log.error("Store Details not available - {}", traceId);
            throw new StDetailsUnavailableException("St Details not available for st");
        }
        List<St> stList = stResponse.getSt().getSts();
        Map<String, List<List<String>>> stDataMap = new HashMap<>();
        Disposable disposable = Flowable.fromIterable(storeList)
                .flatMap(stInfo -> {
                    CRDetail detail = stInfo.getDetail();
                    String spScheduledCount = "SP";
                    String stream = "P";
                    return dataDao.getDept(spScheduledCount,
                            stream,
                            "1111",
                            detail.getData(),
                            DEFAULT,
                            "IE"
                    ).flatMap(resp -> {
                        if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(resp.getCrDetail()) || ObjectUtils.isEmpty(resp.getCrDetail().getCrData())) {
                            log.error("CR data not available for store - {}", stInfo.getNumber());
                            throw new CRDepartmentDetailsUnavailableException("CR data not available for store");
                        }
                        return Single.just(Objects.requireNonNull(stDataMap.put(stInfo.getId(), resp.getDetail().getData()))); // line 2 <--- this is where I am getting the error NPE

                    }).onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                        log.error("Exception occurred while fetching data  - {} {}",stInfo.getNumber(), throwable.getMessage()); // line 3 throwable.getMessage prints "The mapper function returned a null value"

                        return new ArrayList<>();
                    }).toFlowable();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .subscribe(responseList -> {
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                });
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Trace: {} Error while waiting for count down", traceId);
        }
        disposable.dispose();
        return stDataMap;
    }

line 2 is the place where I am getting null and I am not able to resolve. Need help on this
Error stack trace:
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "StDetail.getSt()" because the return value of "StDetail.getSt()" is null
    at com.tesco.store.counts.scheduler.service.impl.TargetedCountServiceImpl.lambda$fetchStoreDetails$4(MyServiceImpl.java:142)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:77)


Exception in thread "RxCachedThreadScheduler-6" io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "StDetail.getSts()" because the return value of "StResponse.getSt()" is null


Please provide the full stacktrace of the NPE.

Why are you null checking the result of stDataMap.put? put will return null if the previous value for the key was not present or was null itself.

@akarnokd updated the stack trace in the post itself. And regarding stDataMap.put map will always have unique value and also it tried it like this storeCrDataMap.put(storeInfo.getId(), resp.getCrDetail().getCrData());
return Single.just(storeCrDataMap);

Your stacktrace doesn't line up with the code you posted. Namings are off. Can't you just debug your code and put a breakpoint on NPE? Or instead of putting everything on the same line, put different dereferences on different line and see which one is tripped?
